# Не могу разобраться где ошибка php

Tags: php

В общем в бд sql записывается все, кроме одного значения
( id_band).

```
 if(isset($_POST['save_edit'])){
    $age=FormChars($_POST['age']);
    $band=FormChars($_POST['allband']);
    $instruments=FormChars($_POST['instruments']);
    $about=FormChars($_POST['about']);
    $edit_info=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("UPDATE  `about` SET `Age` =  $age, `id_band` =  '$band', `instruments` =  '$instruments', `myinfo` =  '$about', WHERE  `id` ='$qq'"));


    header("Location: profile.php");
}
<form method="post">
                <p>Возраст: <?php print $query['Age']; if($edit==true){echo '<input id="inst" type="text" name="age"/>';}?></p> 
                 <p>Группа: <?php print $query['band']; if($edit==true){echo '<select id="inst" size="1" name="allband"><option>Выберите группу</option>'; do {printf ('<option value="%s">%s</option>',$data2['id_band'], $data2['Bandname']);}
                 while($data2=mysql_fetch_array($data)); echo '</select>';}?></p>   
                <p>Инструменты: <?php print $query['instruments']; if($edit==true){echo '<input id="inst" type="text" name="instruments"/>';}?></p>     
                <p>О себе: <?php print $query['myinfo']; if($edit==true){echo '<input id="inst" type="text" name="about"/>';}?></p> 
                <?php if($edit==true){echo '<input id="subsub-reg"type="submit" name="save_edit" value="Сохранить"/>';}else{echo'
                <input id="subsub-reg"type="submit" name="edit" value="Изменить" />';}?>
                </form>
```

Comment: В общем, подсветка работает, это уже хоть что-то. Но у вас и сам код не очень хорошо оформлен. Ну да ладно. Для начала посоветовал бы во-первых, перестать использовать устаревший `mysql_query`, а перейти на библиотеку `mysqli` или `PDO`. Во-вторых в запросе в бд лучше использовать конкатенацию строк: например вместо `mysql_query("UPDATE  `about` SET `Age` =  $age WHERE `id` = 1;")` используйте `mysql_query("UPDATE  `about` SET `Age` =  ".$age." WHERE `id` = 1;")`

Comment: @intro94, а чем конкатенация лучше?

Comment: @BOPOH, может это вопрос личных предпочтений, но мне кажется, что так надёжней. К тому же `$a = 123; echo "qwe$arty";` не будет работать, потому что интерпретатор будет искать переменную `$arty`. В таком случае надо писать `echo "qwe{$a}rty";` Используя конкатенацию я не парю себе мозг при выводе подобных конструкций без пробелов, а также могу смело использовать значения массивов, например `echo "qwe".$a['value']."rty";`

Comment: @intro94, а использование подготовленных запросов с placeholder'ами разве не спасает не только от этой проблемы, но и от sql-инъекций? так что так, как у вас, ни капли не "надежней". А как встраивать переменные в строки я знаю )

Comment: @BOPOH, я и не говорил, что не надо защищаться от sql-инъекций. И я имел ввиду, что надёжней, в плане создания самой строки, а не выполнения запроса. Я своим примером лишь показал, на всякий случай, что такое конкатенация. А уж как именно её использовать - не мне решать. К тому же её использование не распространяется лишь на запись данных полученных из формы в бд. В общем, на мой взгляд, лучше использовать конкатенацию строк. Но сколько программистов, столько и мнений. :D | P.S.: мы отошли от темы. Давайте не будем устраивать холивар. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$band=FormChars($_POST['allband']);
```

Посмотрите что приходит в `$_POST['allband']`, подозреваю что там пустая строка. Вот она и записывается. Учитывая, что остальные поля записываются.

Comment: Не пустая. Через var_dump уже проверял. Вот что приходит string(1) "1"

Comment: @Bagul, берете ваш запрос `"UPDATE...` и выводите его на экран. Если ничего плохого не видите, вставляете его в консоль mysql и смотрите что происходит. А потом уже от этого и надо плясать

Comment: @Bagul И что то у вас запятая перед where стоит, разве этот запрос выполнится? (You have an error in your SQL syntax)